# How to active SetWindowsHookEx after unlock screen?

Tags: c++, winapi, authentication, locking, hook

I'm writing an app that use global hook. Any thing is ok. But after lock windows (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) then login again, my hook function dont work any more.

That I want after I login again, my hook function continue work. How to do that? Thank you!

```
HHOOK _k_hook;
HWND hwnd;

LRESULT __stdcall k_Callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CallNextHookEx(_k_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        //...
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow ) 
{
    //...
    _k_hook = SetWindowsHookExA(13, k_Callback,NULL,0);

    MSG msg;
    while( GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) )
    {
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to rehook after the desktop switches back (the lock screen is a separate desktop), and all I can say is that `SetWinEventHook` will let you catch `EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH`. That's something at least.

Comment: You are setting a global hook. Global hooks **must** be implemented in a DLL, but the code you showed is not in a DLL. This is clearly stated in the SetWindowsHookEx() documentation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, It's `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`, which doesn't AFAIK. I'm actually interested in hearing the counter I suspect you have for that, as that would be a nice insight.

Comment: @chris: I don't have a counter to that. However, the WH_KEYBOARD_LL documentation says it is better to monitor [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645536.aspx) when possible and avoid using WH_KEYBOARD_LL. Besides, there is a logic bug in the above message loop, so maybe the loop is not acting correctly. And on Win7+, Windows itself removes a WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook if it does not respond within a timeout.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Indeed, it does. I have to say that despite being on that page dozens of times, I haven't really noticed the raw input note. I know I've read it, but the likely explanation is that I was just refreshing myself with the documentation and trying to get each of my small, personal, not-necessarily-the-best-way things to just work. Raw input is something I've barely touched, but I'm actually interested to start using it now, thanks.